# JQuery iterate through a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table where I can move rows up or down which I have put an id on the . Now I need to save the the new order of the table.  I am thinking I need to save the rows[index] and  but I have no experience with jquery.  My table is id="rtbl", the button to call the function is "sroute".  I have an alert in the function but that is not working. Just new to jquery, what do I need to do to make this work?

```
$("#sroute").click(function(){
    alert("Hello")
    $("#rtbl tr").each(function() {
        var val1 = $(t.rows[i].cells[0]).text();
        alert(val1) ;
        i++;
    });
});
```

```
<button id="sroute">Save Order</button>
<table id='rtbl'>
   <tr><th>Invoice</th></tr>
   <tr id='789'><td>789</td></tr>
   <tr id='123'><td>123</td></tr>
   <tr id='456'><td>456</td></tr>
</table>
```

So the goal is to update the db field 'stopnum' where invoice 789 stopnum would be 1, invoice 123 stopnum would be 2, and invoice 456 stopnum would be 3.

Answer (score 2):

Rough estimate for the object your db update API will need.  You'll have to adjust it for that.

```js
window.onload = (function(){
document.getElementById('sroute').onclick=( function(){
  var arrayOfInvoices = $('#rtbl tr:not(:eq(0))').map( function(i,el) { return ({ invoice: el.id, stopnum: i+1 }) } ).get();
  alert(JSON.stringify(arrayOfInvoices));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sroute">Save Order</button>
<table id='rtbl'>
   <tr><th>Invoice</th></tr>
   <tr id='789'><td>789</td></tr>
   <tr id='123'><td>123</td></tr>
   <tr id='456'><td>456</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nothing happened.  I think it has to do with stopnum being a db field (shown in the jquery  by user120242)

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Are you submitting this to an API endpoint?  You will need to know what the endpoint expects as input.

Comment: Right now I expected to see the three id's in the console.

Comment: Right, when you click the button it outputs: `[{"invoice":"789","stopnum":1},{"invoice":"123","stopnum":2},{"invoice":"456","stopnum":3}]`.  That's what you wanted right?

Comment: I don't get that.  Nothing happens.  So I put alert("HERE");  above the var arrayOf... and I did not get the alert box.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Should work with the Run Code Snippet button up there and then save order.

Comment: I'm using chrome...Update...I moved the function to the bottom of the page and it worked!  Thank you.  Now to save the stopnum.

Comment: Oh, you may need to wrap your code in $(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */  });  DOM might not be ready yet, so your click event binding might not have taken effect.  The runnable example I have posted in my answer should run fine though.

Comment: Yes it does.  So I've added a function to post to my maintenance page and I'm getting an "Unexpected token" error.  I've also tried a few ways to access each element without luck.```alert(JSON.stringify(arrayOfInvoices));
    
    arrayOfInvoices.forEach(saveStop);    
    function (saveStop) {
       alert(saveStop);
       /*$.post("rec_maint.php",{
          maint: 'invoices',
          rec: "stopnum",
          invoice: saveStop[0][0];
          rstop: saveStop[0][1];*/
    }```

Comment: I don't mind helping, but you should probably make a new question for this.  Give someone else a chance to earn a few points :p  But also because it's good for the site and future people searching for resources on google ending up here.  It's also Stackoverflow policy, including not discussing things in length in comments.

Comment: invoice: saveStop[0][0]; rstop: saveStop[0][1];  syntax error.  supposed to be commas not semicolons for object notation

Comment: See that's the kind of thing.  Imagine someone tearing their hair out trying to figure out what's wrong with their code throwing that token error.  Google search and.. Oh, a semicolon.   And at the same time you award some points to the people who help you.